# Special characters in a web feed

Tags: curl, character-encoding, text

I am running a script to check my gmail from the command line and display the first 35 characters in the title.

```
curl -u username:password --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | \
grep -oPm1 "(?<=<title>)[^<]+" | sed '1d'|cut -b 1-35
```

The script works fine, except when the title contains special characters like `'`, `&` and the like. How can I have them displayed properly? The cut and paste to here displays it correctly, but when I print it to terminal, I get `&#39` for `'` and `&amp` for `&`.

```
Up to 93% Off - Valentine&#39;s Day Today&#39;s Deals Live Now:
Michael Vince • FENDI &amp; More for Men
```

Comment: You need to decode your XML [entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). You also probably want to use a proper xml parser, otherwise you will get into other [problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1870481).

Comment: Are you sure this is a `sed` problem? What does the `sed` input look like?

Comment: `w3m -dump -T text/html <<<"&amp"`

Comment: How do I go about decoding the XML entities? I am not sure it is a 'sed problem', but am pretty sure sed can fix it, but my sed-fu is weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decode the html, so pipe the output trough a decoder:

With `perl`:

```
$ your cammand | perl -MHTML::Entities -le 'while(<>) {print decode_entities($_);}'
```

See the example:

```
$ echo "Ambersand &amp; and Single quote &#39" | perl -MHTML::Entities -le 'while(<>) {print decode_entities($_);}'
Ambersand & and Single quote '
```